# Raspberry Pi B possible sd card issue?

Tags: sd-card, noobs

So, I had 2 kingston SDHC 16 gb cards. They used to work fine on my raspberry pi B until there were a few power outages. When I used them on my computer or video camera they work perfectly fine. But whenever I try to re-install Noobs 1.4.1 on them for my Raspberry pi B, I get these errors seen here.

Is the card somehow corrupt or is it the Raspberry Pi?
if the card is corrupt, why does it still format and function properly?
Is this version of noobs incorrect for the B?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Looks like it got corrupted. 1. You can try scanning it with e2fsck and fsck.fat on a linux box. If it doesn't work. 2. Try re flashing back up image or fresh image of noobs.

Comment: @dastaan I don't have a unit that runs linux, when I scan the disk on windows: http://i.imgur.com/rEnSCjc.png Also I've formatted and reinstalled a new copy of noobs many times with the same results.

Comment: The problem is that corruption is in its rootfs and windows can only access its boot partition and not ext partitions. However, since you've formatted it, it should work fine with fresh copy. Not sure what's going on.

Comment: You say you have formatted and reinstalled many times.  What commands did you use to format the card and reinstall?

Comment: If the exact same thing keeps happening after you've reinstalled the OS, with multiple SD cards, there is not much you can do.  If you get a linux VM (virtual machine, you can run it inside windows) or live CD, you could check the filesystem before and after with `e2fsck` to see if it really is corruption.  Note the author of the duplicate said the problem was fixed by using a better power supply.

Comment: @goldilocks  I have a 2.0amp power supply, i took from my Rasp Pi 2. And I got this error: http://i.imgur.com/wGOUbfm.jpg Although, i was actually able to get into the setup screen this time

Comment: In the images here, the OS finds garbage in an init script that should not be garbage (`mountnfs.sh`) and complains some executables are in the wrong format, implying the same -- the file on disk appears as garbage.  In the pic you link above, pretty much the same thing is going on plus some fundamental system binaries can't be found.  Filesystem corruption isn't the only way to explain this, but it is a very likely one.  However, if you cannot examine the filesystem outside of the pi, or give it to someone who can, there is no way to confirm this.

Comment: In any case, the answer is the same as it is to that other question:  If trying multiple SD cards and power supplies *doesn't* solve the problem, and you've double checked what you are doing is being done correctly, that's the end.  There's nothing more you can do to make it work.